# Change "From" address in offline Gmail?

Tags: gmail, offline

When I use the standard online interface to [compose an email](http://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#compose) in Gmail, I have the option of changing the address in the from box.

Is it possible to access this feature in offline Gmail?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this in the Chrome version.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say so, but no such feature is available in GMail Offline.